# String.Format decimal with sign, fixed number of decimal places, no decimal separator

Tags: .net, vb.net, decimal, string.format

What is the cleanest, most readable way to String.Format a decimal with the following criteria

- start with a sign symbol (+ or -)
- a fixed number of fraction digits
- no decimal separator
- right aligned
- pre-padded with "0"'s

For example

- 123,45 would become "+0012345"
- -1123,45 would become "-0112345"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost certainly want a [Custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to pass to the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method.

The custom format string can contain 2 sections (first for positive, second for negative formatting) for which you can supply the literal `+` or `-`. So to format with 7 characters zero padded this is something like:

```
String.Format("{0:'+'0000000;'-'0000000}",yourValue);
```

However, this will truncate a decimal, and so your input gives

```
123.45 --> +0000123
-1123.45 --> -0001123
```

One simple solution is just multiply your number by 100 (to fix the number of decimal digits to 2) before passing it to the above

Live example: http://rextester.com/SZR8690 (C# - sorry, but only demo's the idea)

This could then be wrapped up into an extension method:

```
<Extension()> 
Public Function ToFixedFormat(ByVal value As Decimal, ByVal numFractionalDigits As Integer)
    Return String.Format("{0:'+'0000000;'-'0000000}",value * Math.Pow(10,numFractionalDigits))
End Function
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/LSAAA60214 (VB.NET)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm fluent in C# too ;) Multiplying: simple and brilliant :)

Comment: @BorisCallens - I thought C# would be ok, but we should always strive to provide code examples in the tagged language of choice. The fixed number of digits was the only part `String.Format` cant do (not without a decimal separator anyway) So your 2 choices are replace the decimal place (as per @Tim's answer) or multiply by the nth power of 10 (as per my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's something better because it looks a bit clumsy, but it works.

I specify the positive and negative format to enforce the plus-sign for positive numbers and a fixed size string. Then i use the `InvariantCulture` to enforce the point as decimal separator (i could have used other cultures too). The last step is to remove the point.

```
Dim value = -1123.45
Dim formatted = value.ToString(
        "+00000.00;-00000.00",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
formatted = formatted.Replace(".", "")
```

As you can see i don't know how to specify **no** decimal separator.